# Record Video and sharing it in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, view, video-capture

In my app I want to give the user the option to record a video and share it. What is the easiest way to achieve this? (I have been trying to add video recording for days now and keep hitting dead ends). Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Have you tried this simple cam capture library https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070) for UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 0):

To allow functionality to record videos within your app, please go to the Apple documentation for UIImagePickerController for taking pictures and movies

[UIImagePickerController Class Reference Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406)

Once you have your video, sharing it is a little more difficult as unlike text or images, the movie file sizes can often be very large and may have to rule out simple sharing via email, text-message etc.

The best way to share in this case, would be to connect to an external API, like YouTube, where you can upload the video from the app. Here's a link to YouTube documentation for this

[YouTube API Documentation Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

I suggest these as good places to start, as this is what you are asking for.

Hope this helps